# Pass more than 1 parameter in Kendo Grid Client Template MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am getting error in passing Multiple Parameters in kendo grid.

What I have done is :

```
  columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeID).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + @Url.Action("Map", "Employee", new { AccountNo = "#=AccountNo#&" , EmployeeID="#=EmployeeeID" }) + "' class='btn btn-primary'>View</a>").Width(90);
```

Type a message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple syntax errors in the client template:

- Remove the extra `&` after the `#=AccountNo#` value
- Add a missing `#` in the #=EmployeeeID#` value

```
columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeID).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + @Url.Action("Map", "Employee", new { AccountNo = "#=AccountNo#" , EmployeeID="#=EmployeeeID#" }) + "' class='btn btn-primary'>View</a>").Width(90);
```